# Deleting table rows in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used sessions to populate the table with the data. My table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <% grand_total = 0 %>
      <% session[:cart].each do |key, item| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= item[:name] %></td>
          <td><%= item[:price] %></td>
          <td><%= text_field_tag(:quantity, item[:quantity]) %>
            <%= link_to("Update", {:action => "update", :id => item[:id]}) %>
          </td>
          <td><%= item[:total_cost] %></td>
          <td>
            <%= link_to("X", {:action => "delete", :id => item[:id]}) %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <% grand_total = grand_total + item[:total_cost] %>
      <% end %>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

I want to delete a table entry as well as the session data for that entry. How do i use the delete method to do this?? I used sessions..

My controller:

```
 def delete
  product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: +1 for using session with a cart :D

Comment: @RichPeck are u being sarcastic towards him?

Comment: No way, we've used it so I was complimenting. I am writing answer to demonstrate!

Comment: still waiting to see your answer @RichPeck

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your table:

```
<table id="cartTable">
```

and and this Javascript:

```
$('#cartTable tr').click({
    $(this).remove();
    return false;
};
```

This will remove the row from your table.

To delete the entry from your sessions you should delete it from the sessions object and from your database as well if you are persisting it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want an AJAX style delete, as it would probably be most fitting for a cart type scenario.

The process how I would do it is fairly simple:

1. Hit the destroy URI asynchronously (`remote: true` option uses UJS to do this)
2. Fill your destroy action out to make the relevant changes server-side
3. Respond to JS requests in your `destroy` action ([`responds_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to)..)
4. Create a `destroy.js.erb` view that makes the UI changes that you require (removing the row, some confirmation message maybe)

Answer (score 0):

http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk - one of our dev apps which has exactly the functionality you seek

Here's how we did it:

---

**Cart Controller**

The `session` variables populate the cart table, but they're still stored by Rails

This means if you want to "delete" a cart record, you'll have to unset the session variable in the backend. This *has* to be done by connecting to Rails & performing a `delete` action (as you already know), so it will be best for me to explain this process for you

We use a `cart_controller` to handle the `delete` action:

```
 #app/controllers/cart_controller.rb 
 def delete
            session[:cart] ||={}
            products = session[:cart][:products]
            id = params[:id]
            all = params[:all]

            #Is ID present?
            unless id.blank?
                    unless all.blank?
                            products.delete(params['id'])
                    else
                            products.delete_at(products.index(id) || products.length)
                    end
            else
                    products.delete
            end

            #Handle the request
            respond_to do |format|
                    format.json { render json: cart_session.build_json }
                    format.html { redirect_to cart_index_path }
            end
end

#config/routes.rb
get 'cart' => 'cart#index', :as => 'cart_index'
post 'cart/add/:id' => 'cart#add', :as => 'cart_add'
delete 'cart/remove(/:id(/:all))' => 'cart#delete', :as => 'cart_delete'
```

This gives us the backend functionality, and an endpoint to call with either an HTTP or JSON (ajax) request. This means in the front end, you can call the `delete` function like this:

```
#app/views/cart/index.html.erb
<%= link_to "Remove", cart_delete_path(item[0]["id"], 1), :class => 'delete', :id => item[0]["id"], :method => :delete, data: { :confirm => "Are You Sure?"}, :remote => :true, :format => :json  %>

#app/assets/javascripts/cart.js
//Cart Remove Links NEED TO OPTIMIZE
$(document).on('click', 'li:not(.shipping) .delete a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            table_overlay(id)

    }).on('ajax:success', 'li:not(.shipping) .delete a', function(e, xhr, data, status){

            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            table_overlay(id);
            cart_count(xhr.qty);
            cart_total(xhr.subtotal);
            if(xhr.qty != "0"){        $('#' + id).animationUp(); }else{ clear_cart();        }

    }).on('ajax:error', 'li:not(.shipping) .delete a', function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#' + id + ' .table_overlay').fadeOut(200);
            alert('Sorry, there was an error!');
    });
```

Gotta refactor the cart removal JS, but hopefully you can see how it sends the data to the server & only on successful callback will it remove the item from the DOM